# Ordinary Generating Function for OEIS A056296?

Tags: co.combinatorics, oeis

The sequence [OEIS A056296](https://oeis.org/A056296) can be obtained using

$
 a(n)={1\over n}\sum_{d\backslash n}\varphi(d)\begin{cases}
  {n/d+2\brace3}-{n/d+1\brace3}, & \text{$6\backslash d$;} \\
  {n/d+2\brace3}-3{n/d+1\brace3}+3{n/d\brace3}, & \text{$3\backslash d$;} \\
  2{n/d+1\brace3}-2{n/d\brace3}, & \text{$2\backslash d$;} \\
  {n/d\brace3}, & \text{else.} \\
 \end{cases}
$

or replacing the Stirling subset numbers

$
 a(n)={1\over n}\sum_{d\backslash n}\varphi(d)\begin{cases}
  3^{n/d}-2^{n/d}, & \text{$6\backslash d$;} \\
  \left(3^{n/d}-2^{n/d}+1\right)/2, & \text{$3\backslash d$;} \\
  \left(2\cdot3^{n/d}-3\cdot2^{n/d}\right)/3, & \text{$2\backslash d$;} \\
  \left(3^{n/d}-3\cdot2^{n/d}+3\right)/6, & \text{else.} \\
 \end{cases}
$

Is there an ordinary generating function for this sequence?

Comment: Is $d\backslash n$ a common notation for $d|n$ nowadays?

Comment: @Gerald, I think d\n is the notation I learned at the Ross program 50 years ago. But I haven't seen it much since.

Comment: Knuth uses $d\backslash n$ in Concrete Mathematics.

Comment: A Dirichlet generating function might be a better idea here.

Comment: The cases in the formulae are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: The recent edit to the question makes it more difficult to see how the answer is derived therefrom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that

$ \sum_{d>0}{\varphi(d)\over6d}\begin{cases}
  -6\log(1-3x^d)+6\log(1-2x^d), & \text{$6\backslash d$;} \\
  -3\log(1-3x^d)+3\log(1-2x^d)-3\log(1-x^d), & \text{$3\backslash d$;} \\
  -4\log(1-3x^d)+6\log(1-2x^d), & \text{$2\backslash d$;} \\
  -\log(1-3x^d)+3\log(1-2x^d)-3\log(1-x^d), & \text{else.} \\
 \end{cases}
$

works.  Kociemba's o.g.f. for [OEIS A000013](https://oeis.org/A000013) was very helpful to me.